# How do I override package language files in Laravel 5.1

Tags: localization, laravel-5.1

According to Laravel Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/localization#overriding-package-language-files

> for example, if you need to override the English language lines in messages.php for a package named skyrim/hearthfire, you would place a language file at:  resources/lang/vendor/hearthfire/en/messages.php.

I currently have the package activewebsite/enterprise-entity package that I am including in my project.  It contains a language file:

`vendor/activewebsite/enterprise-entity/src/resources/lang/en/phone.php`

This file contains translations for types of phone numbers:

```
'phone_1' => 'Home',
'phone_2' => 'Work',
'phone_3' => 'Mobile',
'phone_4' => 'Office',
'phone_5' => 'Fax',
'phone_6' => 'Fax 2',
'phone_7' => 'Home 2',
'phone_8' => 'Direct',
```

Following the example above, I attempted to override this file by creating the following directory:

```
resources/lang/vendor/enterprise-entity/en/phone.php
```

containing an additional phone number specific to this project:

```
    'phone_9' => 'Rapid Rewards Text Alert Number',
```

But the the translation does not come through to the front-end.  The only way I've been able to get the translation to appear is to edit the language file within the enterprise-entity package.

I found this thread: https://octobercms.com/forum/post/localication-problems-where-to-overwrite-octobercms-lang-settings-in-general
Where another user seems to be having a similar issue, but it is suggested that they use the directory structure:

```
/lang/{locale}/{vendor}/{plugin}/lang.php
```

so I attempted

```
/lang/en/activewebsite/enterprise-entity/phone.php
```

with no luck.

Can anyone tell me what I may be getting wrong here?  I've attempted running a php artisan optimize after each change to see if that could clear things up, but no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't find the package you mentioned anywhere, is it an imaginary package?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the folder structure needs to use the NAMESPACE for the package, camelcase, not follow the same naming convention/directory structure as in the package or in the docs.  So, for my example, the namespace used for the enterprise-entity package is EnterpriseEntity, camelcased would be enterpriseEntity.
The correct directory structure would be:

```
resources/lang/vendor/enterpriseEntity/en/phone.php
```

Answer (score 1):

From Laravel Official Documentation

**Overriding Package Language Files**

Some packages may ship with their own language files. Instead of changing the package's core files to tweak these lines, you may override them by placing files in the  `resources/lang/vendor/{package}/{locale}` directory.

So, for example, if you need to override the English translation strings in `messages.php` for a package named `skyrim/hearthfire`, you should place a language file at:  `resources/lang/vendor/hearthfire/en/messages.php`. Within this file, you should only define the translation strings you wish to override. Any translation strings you don't override will still be loaded from the package's original language files.